# cinema production

Tags: phrase-meaning

If a movie has been shown in a cinema four times, does that mean four cinema productions have been shown, or one cinema production has been shown four times?

The following use of "cinema productions" strikes me as unusual:

> Ramiro Alanis previously broke the record for “**most cinema productions** attended of the same film” in 2019, after watching “Avengers: Endgame” 191 times. But in 2021, Arnaud Klein beat him out by watching “Kaamelott: First Installment” 204 times, according to a news release from Guinness World Records. -- [CNN article](https://www.cnn.com/2022/04/17/us/florida-world-record-spider-man-trnd/index.html)

Comment: It is not a use of "productions" that would be recognised by most English speakers. The text seems to be referring more to "screenings" than productions.

Comment: @RonaldSole Strange to say, the source text is a CNN article.

Comment: The common way of describing this is indeed "a screening", as @RonaldSole suggests. It's possible CNN used the term "cinema production" because that's the term Guinness uses for it, but to me a "cinema production" is the movie itself, not a screening of it, so it doesn't make sense for it to be "attended".

Comment: Could "viewings" work too?

Comment: Yes "viewings" should work in this case

Comment: @Apollyon "viewing" is similar, but not the same. A "viewing" is the act of viewing the movie (or whatever), rather than the act of showing it. Also, a "viewing" can refer to the time a dead body is presented in a private room for family and friends to see before the funeral and burial, so to "attend a viewing" usually means to go see a dead body.

Comment: @gotube - I often frequent UK art galleries and I can think of a number of viewings which felt like going to see dead bodies.

Comment: @Apollyon - the text “most cinema productions attended of the same film” is shown in quotation marks by CNN. This indicates that CNN were reproducing it from somewhere else, in this case [Guinness World Records](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/79137-most-cinema-productions-attended-same-film).

Comment: It says "of the same film". It means that Ramiro Alanis watched the *same* film 191 times, not 191 different films.

Comment: @WeatherVane We all know the intended meaning; the issue is whether "cinema production" is used naturally.

Comment: @Apollyon except the OP, see the actual question asked.

Comment: @Apollyon If you already knew the intended meaning, why did you ask about it, and not whether it's natural?

Comment: @gotube Because the sentence is from a reputable source.

Comment: @gotube And it doesn't hurt to confirm my suspicion with others.

Comment: If the answer to "If a movie has been shown in a cinema four times, does that mean four cinema productions have been shown, or one cinema production has been shown four times?" is the latter, then it confirms my suspicion.

Comment: My statement, "The following use of "cinema productions" strikes me as unusual," shows I think the sentence is unnatural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way of describing this is indeed "a screening".

It's possible CNN used the term "cinema production" because that's the term Guinness uses for it, but to me a "cinema production" is the movie itself, not a screening of it, so it doesn't make sense for it to be "attended".